How do I make Putty adjust the terminal & re-wrap lines when I resize the window?
When using the Windows ssh command in either a Windows Terminal or a traditional Windows console, if I resize the window after running a command that echoed long wrapping lines (eg. cat /var/log/syslog), it will automatically re-wrap the lines to new window size.
When doing the same in Putty it will not do this, the lines stay truncated requiring you to re-execute the command after the window is extended.
Is there a way to make Putty behave like ssh and adjust existing console output when the window is resized?


Is there a way to make Putty behave like ssh

ssh doesn't resize anything, it's just a tunnel forwarding the characters from one computer to another. Resizing is done (or not) by the terminal emulator such as Window Terminal.
So what you actually want to ask: Is there a way to make PuTTY behave like Windows Terminal or Windows console?
I'm afraid PuTTY itself cannot do it. Its changelog, dating back for 25 years (when I doubt any terminal out there offered this feature) doesn't mention the word "re-wrap" or "re-flow", spelled with or without a hyphen, nor does any presence of the word "resize" refer to this feature.
As a workaround, you can run screen or tmux, they rewrap the lines for you on the server side and send over to PuTTY the reformatted output.
